# Using an HTML Tag for a Directive in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

In Angular (2+), typically components would be added to templates using HTML tags, and directives would be added using HTML attributes: in both cases this is achieved through the selector argument within the @Component/@Directive decorator:

```
<!-- component set up using-- selector: 'my-component' -->
<my-component></my-component>
<!-- directive set up using-- selector: '[myDirective]' -->
<div myDirective></div>
```

I tested to see if  I could set up a directive that will use an HTML tag instead of attribute, and it seemed to work fine:

```
<!-- directive set up using-- selector: 'my-tag-directive' -->
<my-tag-directive></my-tag-directive>
```

I would just like to know if this is officially supported in Angular.

Comment: Note: we're currently using Angular 2 so I tested on that, although the intention is to upgrade.

Comment: By saying "seemed to work fine" you meant that you didn't get any errors or some logic in that `Directive` works fine?

Comment: ya angular 5 it is deprecated

Comment: @Buczkowski I set it up, added it to my template, and added alert('hello') to the ngOnInit, and that worked without generating any errors.

Comment: @ChellappanV do you have a link? The link provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972583/2661556 seems to suggest it's allowed.

Comment: sorry my mistake i have following max udamey course where he had mentioned don't use class or element for directive

Comment: @ChellappanV np, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it could be tag as well see this documentation for more info

https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Comment: But can it be a 'made-up' tag? From the link you have provided (and others I've found) it doesn't look like it. They are just binding to existing, well-established tags, not 'new' ones. I feel you can do this for a component tag, for instance, but not completely generate a new one.

Comment: EDIT to previous: Nevermind, I've actually tested this and can confirm THIS WORKS.